# How to make special new folder in right click?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, execute-command

I want to create folder but it's name date of current day.
I know how to make it in terminal by this command:

```
mkdir $(date -I)
```

How to add this to right click to be easy?

Comment: The right-click menu can't be edited.

Comment: have a look at gnome scripts.

Comment: First mention whether you want this in gnome-terminal menu or in nautilus menu ?

Comment: i'm using xubuntu desktop